# Variable in firewall-cmd command

Tags: bash, shell, firewalld

I'm trying to do a script in Bash to add some firewall rules.

The variable I'm passing isn't working, I guess I'm doing the substitution wrong.

```sh
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="$IP/32" port port=10000 protocol=tcp accept'
```

Returns

```sh
Error: INVALID_ADDR: $IP/32
```

What's wrong here, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please post the output of `echo $IP` to check the bash variable IP is correctly set.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are single-quoting the entire string, so you are passing the literal string `$IP`. You can break out of the single quotes temporarily by adding a closing single quote before the variable and a new single quote after it.

```sh
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="'$IP'/32" port port=10000 protocol=tcp accept'
```